# How to handle empty CONTAINS() query parameter in ASP.NET SqlDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, full-text-search, contains

How can we handle empty ControlParameter values in SQL `CONTAINS()` condition without using code-behind (so that it returns all results)? Looking probably for something like `LIKE '%'` or `WHERE (1=1)`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbSearch" runat="server" placeholder="Search" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceA" runat="server" ConnectionString="..." 
  SelectCommand="SELECT [Columns] FROM [Table] 
                 WHERE CONTAINS([Column],@searchText) ORDER BY [Time] DESC">
   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="searchText" ControlID="tbSearch" 
                            PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="?" />
   </SelectParameters>        
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I know that one way is to create a dynamic query in code behind, but maybe there's other way to do that with just markup.

EDIT: ControlParameter default value is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

take a look into IS NULL property of mssql

Answer (score 0):

Make the `WHERE` something like `WHERE CONTAINS([Column], COALESCE(@searchText, [Column]))`
Basically the idea is that if `@searchText` is null, use `[Column]`, and `[Column]` contains `[Column]` so everything should be returned.

Might have issues if `@searchText` isn't null but just blank, you'd have use a `CASE` statement to check for length or something similar.

For empty string handling, I couldn't get the 2nd param of CONTAINS to accept a case statement, so this should work:
`WHERE [COLUMN] = CASE WHEN LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(@searchText, '')))) = 0 THEN [COLUMN] ELSE @searchText END`
Obviously you can then change the '=' to `LIKE` if needed.

Comment: Well, I actually need that empty string handling, since that's the value of empty textbox.

Comment: added an edit for empty strings...possibly not the most efficient.

Comment: The main problem is I need full-text CONTAINS() search. Else it would be a simple `WHERE Column LIKE '%'`.